# What is a great way to remember how to script

Tags: lua, luau

I keep forgetting what stuff does every now and then. at one point I got so good I was going to make tutorials for beginners but now I'm back to mediocre scripting level.

Comment: The only way is to keep scripting.

Comment: Keep scripts or solutions that you are proud of in a repository; document problems and solutions that you investigated and want to keep in mind. Basically write tutorials for your future self

Comment: Relax. Soon, the writing of scripts will be completely taken over by artificial intelligence. And you (and I) will be busy with hard physical labor. Glory to the robots!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'Comments in Code as Documentation'

```
-- SomeCode.lua -- Version: 0.01 -- Author: Code R. -- Date: --:--:--
--[[ I put out and return the String: Lua
     Example: lua SomeCode.lua
]]
local str = _VERSION:sub(1, 3) -- Method sub(1, 3) on String _VERSION
print(str)
return(str)
```

Than other People have a chance to understand whatfore this is too.

EDIT
I love REXX
A REXX Script has to be start with a Comment `/* I am REXX Code */`
Thats a Coercion thats makes Sense and even it is easy to use `say(sourceline([number]))` to put it out as a minimalistic: HELP!